# How can I change a certain attribute in a certain object with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I try to update an object to a certain attribute, but after the new rendering I always get the error message that `usePl` is not a map function.
For example, I would like to change the image attribute in object 2.

```js
const pl = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bezeichnung: 'fit4Assembly Woche 1 -3',
    erstellungsDatum: '28.07.2020',
    ersteller: 'Max Maier',
    aufgaben: ['Aufgabe 1', 'Aufgabe 2', 'Aufgabe 3'],
    gruppe: 'Gruppe 1',
    bild: ''
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bezeichnung: 'fit4Assembly Woche 1 -3',
    erstellungsDatum: '28.07.2020',
    ersteller: 'Max Maier',
    aufgaben: ['Aufgabe 1', 'Aufgabe 2', 'Aufgabe 3'],
    gruppe: 'Gruppe 2',
    bild: ''
  }
];

const [usePl, setUl] = React.useState(pl);

async function handleInputChangeBild(event, id) {
  [...]
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    setUl((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [id]: e.target.result //For examble the ID is 2
    }));
  };
  [...]
}
```

Comment: setUl((prevState) => ([
      ...prevState,
      [id]: e.target.result //For examble the ID is 2
    ]))

Answer (score 1):

You could map through the previous state array (in your example), and update the attribute for your element with the expected ID, keep the other elements unchanged just by returning itself on each iteration

```js
async function handleInputChangeBild(event, id) {
  [...]
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    setUl((prevState) => prevState.map(el => {
      if (el.id === id) {
        return {
          ...el,
          'your-expected-attribute': e.target.result 
        }
      } else {
        return el
      }
    }));
  };
  [...]
}
```